# Rails 4: Error when installing tiny_tds gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have developed a rails web project with Ruby v2 and Rails v4. It was perfectly working in my current system and when i tried to run this project in another Linux machine (Ubuntu 12.4 ) i am getting a Tidy_tds error .

This error is showing at the time of `bundle install` ,

Error Details below

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.                                                                                                                                

    /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb                                                                                                                                       
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... yes                                                                                                                                                       
checking for sybfront.h... no                                                                                                                                                                     
-----                                                                                                                                                                                             
freetds is missing.    
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary                                                                                                                          
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may                                                                                                                     
need configuration options.                                                                                                                                                                       

Provided configuration options:                                                                                                                                                                   
        --with-opt-dir                                                                                                                                                                            
        --without-opt-dir                                                                                                                                                                         
        --with-opt-include
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib                                                                                                                                                          
        --with-make-prog                                                                                                                                                                          
        --without-make-prog                                                                                                                                                                       
        --srcdir=.                                                                                                                                                                                
        --curdir                                                                                                                                                                                  
        --ruby=/home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby                                                                                                                                       
        --enable-lookup                                                                                                                                                                           
        --disable-lookup  
--with-iconv-dir                                                                                                                                                                          
        --without-iconv-dir                                                                                                                                                                       
        --with-iconv-include                                                                                                                                                                      
        --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include                                                                                                                                              
        --with-iconv-lib       
--without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib                                                                                                                                                      
        --with-freetds-dir                                                                                                                                                                        
        --without-freetds-dir                                                                                                                                                                     
        --with-freetds-include                                                                                                                                                                    
        --without-freetds-include=${freetds-dir}/include   
--with-freetds-lib                                                                                                                                                                        
        --without-freetds-lib=${freetds-dir}/lib                                                                                                                                                  

extconf failed, exit code 1      
Gem files will remain installed in /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/tiny_tds-0.6.1 for inspection.                                                                                          
Results logged to /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/tiny_tds-0.6.1/gem_make.out                                                                                     
An error occurred while installing tiny_tds (0.6.1), and Bundler cannot continue.                                                                                                                 
Make sure that `gem install tiny_tds -v '0.6.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have also tried installing tiny_tds seperatly, but still i am getting the same issue

```
gem install tiny_tds -v '0.6.1'
```

My gem file,

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'tiny_tds' 
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jquery-ui-rails' # jquery ui

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use sqlserver as the database for Active Record
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', :git => 'https://github.com/nextgearcapital/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.git'
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails" 
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'formtastic'
```

Why is this error appearing and how to solve this issue.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Looks like you don't have freetds installed on this machine:

```
sudo apt-get install freetds-dev
```

If you see the details of the [freetds-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/freetds-dev/filelist) package you will see it has the missing file `sybfront.h`

There is no gem that I know for `freetds` and building the `tiny_tds` gem requires it to compile.  However it should be possible for you build your own version of the gem using `MiniPortile`.

Rather than using the normal `gem install` mechanism you need to clone the `tiny_tds` from GitHub and then build a native gem for your environment.  This process will include downloading a specific version of `freetds` which is used to compile the gem against.

This should get you round the problem of not being able to install `freetds-dev` package, but does have the disadvantage that if `tiny_tds` gem is updated in the future you will need to repeat this process each time - you can't simply take advantage of `bundle update`.

The steps you need to follow are detailed [here](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds#using-miniportile).

Comment: thanks for the information. Is it possible to install freetds as a gem, because i am trying to setup my project in a VM which i dont have Admin privileges.

Comment: On fedora, do `sudo yum install freetds-devel`

Comment: On Mac, do `brew install freetds`

Answer (score 13):

For MacOS you need additional lib installed.

```
brew install freetds
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me in `Ubuntu 17.04`

Install `wget` to download packages from remote URL

```
$ sudo apt-get install wget
```

Install dependencies

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
$ sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```

Download remote file

```
$ wget ftp://ftp.freetds.org/pub/freetds/stable/freetds-1.00.21.tar.gz
```

Unzip

```
$ tar -xzf freetds-1.00.21.tar.gz
```

Configure and Run Test for the package in your system

```
$ cd freetds-1.00.21
$ sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-tdsver=7.3
$ sudo make
```

Now, Install

```
$ sudo make install
```

Now install the gem

```
$ gem install tiny_tds -v '2.0.0'
```

> If still, you cannot install the gem `tiny_tds` then try using sudo
>   `$ sudo gem install tiny_tds -v '2.0.0'`

**Output**

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed tiny_tds-2.0.0
Parsing documentation for tiny_tds-2.0.0
Installing ri documentation for tiny_tds-2.0.0
Done installing documentation for tiny_tds after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I get an `/freetds-1.00.21/missing autoconf` when i run `sudo make`. WIll report back if I figure it out

Comment: 5 months later... `sudo apt-get install autoconf` fixed that. `sudo make` and `sudo make install` now work. I have `tiny_tds` working on the WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux`. So happy!