# tiny_tds gem installation issue on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, tiny-tds

I have tried to install gem tiny_tds on Rails 5, but not able to install. I have googled it and tried all the solution. But there is no solution. Can you please suggest me to install it. 
Below are the solutions I have tried,

[Rails 4: Error when installing tiny_tds gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593086/rails-4-error-when-installing-tiny-tds-gem)

sudo apt-get install freetds-dev

Comment: What happens when you try to install? Do you get an error?

Comment: If you get an error, post the error. If you've tried various installation methods, post them.

Comment: always helpful are informations about your os and ruby version. the more the better.

Answer (score 0):

tiny_tds gem can be easily installed from terminal using following command:

```
$ gem install tiny_tds
```

If any other issue you are facing with tiny_tds gem you can refer the documentation of gem:
https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `freetds` library installed in case of MacOS

```
brew install freetds
```

Answer (score 0):

Debian 10
Rails: 5.2
Ruby 2.5

### How to Install FreeTDS:

- source: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/ruby/ubuntu/

#### Use the Terminal with Root or Sudo permissions to run the following commands:

```
wget ftp://ftp.freetds.org/pub/freetds/stable/freetds-1.00.27.tar.gz
tar -xzf freetds-1.00.27.tar.gz
cd freetds-1.00.27
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-tdsver=7.3
make
sudo make install
cd ..
gem install tiny_tds
```

This should get you started.